# Gradient Filter prevents click event in an IE9 DIV where there is no text

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, linear-gradients

I hate to dredge up IE9 issues, but amazingly I haven't seen a post on this.

If a div has a gradient `filter` set, the `click` event no longer works on "empty" areas of a div. If the div contains text, the `click` event will work on the text only.

Any ideas of a way to overcome this?

I've written a gradient generator and would like it to be ie9 compatible. So solutions need to be specific to using `filter` as opposed to replacing it with something else.

Of course the example snippet below need to be run in `IE9` emulation mode to see the problem.

```js
var test1 = document.getElementById("test1");
test1.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#327796', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0)";
test1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("addEventListener clicked 1")
});

var test2 = document.getElementById("test2");
test2.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#327796', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0)";
test2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("addEventListener clicked 2")
});

var test3 = document.getElementById("test3");
test3.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("addEventListener clicked 3")
});
```

```css
.div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="div" id="test1"></div>
<div class="div" id="test2">Some<br>Text</div>
<div class="div" id="test3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - The simplest solution seems to be inserting a child div with height and width equal to 100%. This passes the event up to the parent div without any fuss.